# text() doesn't append to second <span> on the same line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jQuery `text()` function does not append `option` from selection field to the `span`. I have two `select` fields in the same `div`. They are different and contain dynamically created numbers.

```js
function myFunction(selector) {
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 999; i++) {
      var text = '00' + i;
      selector.options[i - 1] = new Option(text.substr(text.length - 3, 3));
    }
  }
  //usage:
myFunction(document.getElementById("patient_code"));

$('#patsiendikoodi_label #patient_code ').change(function(i, text) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.prev().find('.patsiendikoodi_label_nr').text($(this).find('option:selected').text());
}).change();



function patsient(selector) {
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 99; i++) {
      var text = '0' + i;
      selector.options[i - 1] = new Option(text.substr(text.length - 2, 2));
    }
  }
  //usage:
patsient(document.getElementById("patient_code2"));

$('#patsiendikoodi_label #patient_code2 ').change(function(i, text) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.prev().find('#patsiendi_kood').text($(this).find('option:selected').text());
  console.log("WRITTEN");
}).change();
```

```html
<div id="patsiendikoodi_label" class="col-sm-10">
  <label class="control-label">Kood:</label>
  <h4 style="color: #0DD31B; font-weight: bold;"><span id="ravimi_nimi"></span><?php foreach( $result as $row ){echo $row['user_code']; }?>- <span class="patsiendikoodi_label_nr"></span><span id="patsiendi_kood">-</span></h4>

  <select data-placeholder="" id="patient_code" class="chosen-select form-control" tabindex="2">
  </select>

  <select data-placeholder="" id="patient_code2" class="chosen-select form-control" tabindex="2">
  </select>

</div>
```

I am generating `option` values from the JavaScript. If I put the second `select` field in another div, it will append the selected option to the span. This picture should be better than my explanation.

[image]

But no matter what I do, it doesn't add the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the second handler, `prev()` is finding the previous `select` element, not the `h4` you *want* to search in.

Use `prevAll('h4');` to find that element.

```js
$('#patient_code2').change(function(i, text) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.prevAll('h4').find('#patsiendi_kood').text($(this).find('option:selected').text());
  console.log("WRITTEN");
}).change();

function myFunction(selector) {
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 999; i++) {
      var text = '00' + i;
      selector.options[i - 1] = new Option(text.substr(text.length - 3, 3));
    }
  }
myFunction(document.getElementById("patient_code"));

$('#patient_code').change(function(i, text) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.prev().find('.patsiendikoodi_label_nr').text($(this).find('option:selected').text());
}).change();


function patsient(selector) {
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 99; i++) {
      var text = '0' + i;
      selector.options[i - 1] = new Option(text.substr(text.length - 2, 2));
    }
  }
patsient(document.getElementById("patient_code2"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="patsiendikoodi_label" class="col-sm-10">
  <label class="control-label">Kood:</label>
  <h4 style="color: #0DD31B; font-weight: bold;"><span id="ravimi_nimi"></span><?php foreach( $result as $row ){echo $row['user_code']; }?>- <span class="patsiendikoodi_label_nr"></span><span id="patsiendi_kood">-</span></h4>

  <select data-placeholder="" id="patient_code" class="chosen-select form-control" tabindex="2">
  </select>

  <select data-placeholder="" id="patient_code2" class="chosen-select form-control" tabindex="2">
  </select>

</div>
```

Of course, since `id`s are unique in a document, you could really just say:

```
$('#patsiendi_kood').text( $(this).find('option:selected').text() );
```

Comment: Jesus... Long days. Thank you sir!